# Could someone interpret this line of code? 

Tags: c#

```
int salesTeamId = person == null ? -1 : person.SalesTeam.Id;
```

From what I can piece together:

1. int SalesTeamId is a variable and person is being assigned to the variable.

After that I'm lost. Any guidance?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a ternary statement.  I translated it into a if/else block for you for readability.

```
int salesTeamId;

if(person == null)
{
   salesTeamId = -1;
}
else
{
   salesTeamId = person.SalesTeam.Id;
}
```

Comment: @Dylan: Thank you for pointing out the missed .SalesTeam reference

Answer (score 8):

That is [the Ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  It is a shorthand `if` statement equivalent to:

```
int salesTeamId;
if( person == null )
{
    salesTeamId = -1;
}
else
{
    salesTeamId = person.SalesTeam.Id;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It means,

```
int salesTeamId;

if (person == null) 
   salesTeamId = -1;
 else 
   salesTeamId = person.SalesTeam.Id;
```

Answer (score 3):

It's called the [*conditional operator*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4213hs1.aspx).

> The conditional operator (? :) is a ternary operator (it takes three
>   operands). The conditional operator works as follows:
>
> - The first operand is implicitly converted to bool. It is evaluated and
>     all side effects are completed before continuing.
> - If the first operand
>     evaluates to true (1), the second operand is evaluated.
> - If the first
>     operand evaluates to false (0), the third operand is evaluated.

Your example is roughly equivalent to this code:

```
int salesTeamId;
if (person == null)
{
   salesTeamId = -1;
}
else
{
   salesTeamId = person.SalesTeam.Id;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its an implicit if statement (called a ternary operator).

Basically its checking if person is null, return -1 else return person.SalesTeam.id. The return value is then assigned directly to the salesTeamId variable.

```
int salesTeamId;
if(person == null)
{
salesTeamId = -1;
}
else
{
salesTeamId = person.SalesTeam.Id
}
```

is directly equivalent

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to

```
int salesTeamId;
if (person == null)
    salesTeamId = -1;
else
    salesTeamId = person.SalesTeam.Id;
```

Check [?: Operator (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If person is null, then salesTeamId is assigned -1.
If person is null null, then salesTeamId is assigned person.SalesTeam.Id.

The tertiary operator is an if-then-else statement embedded onto one line (usually! it can be spread across multiple lines, but that defeats the point somewhat).

It may clear things up to add some parenthesis:

```
int salesTeamId = (person == null ? -1 : person.SalesTeam.Id);
```

The following pseudocode may also help:

```
int salesTeamId = (IF person == null THEN USE -1 ELSE USE person.SalesTeam.Id );
```